# Re-requesting FB permissions using the iOS FB SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

Say a user gives my app the required FB permissions then removes it at a later date/time. Can I re-request these permissions when the user reopens the app? I can read the permissions to see if the app still has them but is there a way to re-request them if they're missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can re-request them. Just use the standard requestNewReadPermissions or requestNewPublishPermissions methods on FBSession. But be careful when re-requesting permissions, and only re-request the permissions that your app absolutely needs to operate (because the user probably removed those permissions for a reason). You should make it clear to the user why your app needs these permissions before asking for them again.