# iOS facebook - re-requesting missing permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, email, authentication, permissions

My iOS app is enabled for Facebook login. The app requires to access the email of the user. While the user can choose to not share his / her email, in such a scenario I want to show an alert and allow the user to login with Facebook once again. Basically, if the email is not shared the app cannot be used.

I am able to check if the user has indeed shared his / her email, generate the alert. After this I am logging the user out of the app (`[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];`). Next time, when the login button is touched once again, I see the message "You have already authorised ...". There is no provision for the user to enable email sharing.

How do I allow the user to enable the email sharing?

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947979/re-requesting-fb-permissions-using-the-ios-fb-sdk) but I do not see a way to get hold of the FBSession object [SDK 4]. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Some Facebook accounts have no email (e.g. sign up to Facebook using phone number, etc). I would suggest, if your app requires email, to ask user to input email separately on your app.

Answer (score 1):

Ask again for same permission with out calling logout method of facebook sdk. If [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] is not nil, it will be treated as a reauthorization for that user and will pass the "rerequest" flag to the login dialog.